# Date changing when passed to express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Utterly confused about time zones. I pass a Date object as a value in an object I'm posting from React to Express and then to MongoDB using Mongoose.

It seems to change randomly when I send the post request? At first I thought it was that Node/Express was running in UTC by default. In the browser console it outputs as my local time, then in the server console it outputs in UTC, but if I use `new Date()` server-side it generates an object that says my local time. Why is this the case?

I'm trying to save data about flash cards, one of which is the time the card was last reviewed. I want to serve the card to the client if a certain interval has passed, but I'm not sure the best way to handle this with the time zone differences. Is there a way to set the server time zone to the client time zone? What's the best way to smooth this interaction.

TIA!

Comment: Best way is to fix everything to UTC, then convert it to their local time (on React) when you want to display.

You might want to read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Comment: A `Date` object just contains a numeric timestamp. That timestamp is timezone-agnostic. It's only when you convert it to a string that it uses the local timezone of the current machine to format the output. I expect if you execute `new Date().toISOString();` you will see that it outputs the same thing on any machine (if not, that would suggest the clock on the machine is wrong).